# Trying to access Index of MVC controller, Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1

So.. i have a MVC webpage. I have defined a Controller

```
public class NinjaController : Controller
{
    // GET: Ninja
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The my routes are set up like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "Login",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
    }
}
```

And i have a Folder in the Views folder that is named Ninja and an Index.cshtml file in there that looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Very simple... This is a business application with lots of different settings and configurations... If i do the exact same thing in a new solution it works just fine...

However when i try to access (`http://localhost:1235/Ninja`) view i get the following error:

```
{"A public action method 'Login' was not found on controller 'Stimline.Xplorer.Web.Controllers.NinjaController'."}
```

To me it seems like there should be something confusing the routing function.. but i have no idea where this logic could be placed... anyone have any suggestions?

Interesting fact: If i change the name of the method from Index() to OhYea() and create a corresponding view everything works as expected....

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:1235/Ninja/Index`

Comment: Your default routing in the routing table goes to Login. Change it to Index or specify ninja/Index in the URL

Comment: Stefan; if you write an answer with that i will accept your answer... since you were first. If not i will accept James answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routing configuration is saying that pretty much all routes should go to `Login` which is why your `Ninja` route doesn't work.

The recommended way of enforcing authentication against a particular route is to use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx). To summarise, keep your default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default", 
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Ninja", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But restrict your `NinjaController` to authorized users only

```
[Authorize]
public class NinjaController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: With this solution to the authorize problem i will have to add [Authorize] on 99% of all the controllers... :) is there are more general way of doing it?

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen yep, that's exactly what global filters are for :) Just register the `AuthorizeAttribute` in your `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in `Global.asax.cs`

Comment: Perfect.. You are awesome.. have a great day :)